# How can i find the Line that Contains the exception when Using methods that Parse the Data in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, methods

so this is how my trouble began...i made a cs file that contains all of my helper methods within my projects,its somewhat of a toolbox for me...one of the methods is the following :

```
 static public decimal ToDecimal(this string str)
        {
            return decimal.Parse(str);
        }
```

as this method suggests,it lets me do .ToDecimal to different variables within my project,its a way of improving the speed while coding

now here is my problem:
whenever the parse of the decimal.parse(str); fails,the IDE directs me to the method ToDecimal...

NOT to the actual line that calls the method...and that had me stuck for a day on a project to figure the real exception out...
so my question is this :
is there a way to find the line within the solution that is actually causing the exception? i.e the line that the exceptioned method was called at...

**reminding you guys that i have called the same method (ToDecimal()) over 1k times within my solution... so im tryin to figure out Which of those 1k times is the one thats causing the exception...
thank you !**

Comment: Do you have custom error handling?  Because the Stack trace should give you what line called the `ToDecimal()` method.

Comment: im not sure if you fully understood what i tried to explain...Imagine i have  ToDecimal Made in mytools.cs and i called it in the main.cs to parse some decimal....now here is the thing...visual studio which is my IDE shows the ToDecimal in Mytools...which is where the method was made...not the one i called within the Main cs...so i cant pinpoint the location of the method call action that is causing the exception :s hope its more clear now

Comment: No, I fully understood.  If you look through the entire stack trace, it shows you exactly what line called what function.

Comment: Yep,you are right.although i need to know this...is there a way to make my IDE (visual studio 2013) Show me the call line instead of opening my class and showing me the method ?

Comment: take a look at your stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this code

```
static public decimal ToDecimal(this string str){
   decimal dec;
   if (decimal.TryParse(str, out dec))
   {
      return dec;
   }
   else
   {
      MessageBox.Show(str);
      return 0.0;
   }
}
```

Whenever parsing throw an exception, the if statement will fail and else part will give you the string which caused exception.

You can also attach a break point in the else statement.

Comment: Useful for debugging, but you probably don't want this in production code.  Users probably don't want to see that message.

Comment: The question is how to identify that perticular string. You will get it displayed when the error occurs, Messagebox is used to make it simple. Breakpoint will be a better option.

Comment: All to often, this type of code ends up making it to production.  Nobody sees it for a long time because the data is clean and then suddenly some day a user reports the Message box and wants to know what is going on.

Comment: So writing the exception to a log will be a better option. right?

Comment: A better option, yes, but you may not know when to ask the user for the log file.  Also if you use Assert, you can safely leave the code in release, it will do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a try/catch and looking into the Call Stack is hard?